# How can I handle this connection error with Selenium(Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web, web-scraping

Good night, I'm facing a problem with this code, when I run this script on my own Pc it works perfectly but when I deploy it to heroku it doesn't work, but I need to deploy it, cause I can't let my pc 24/7:

```
    def webScrap(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
        options.add_argument('start-maximized')
        options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
        options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
        options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.fump.ufmg.br")
(...)
```

I'm  getting this error when trying to connect to specific websites

> Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I tried some others as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and it worked, I've researched a lot about this problem and I've found some arguments to add but none of them have worked, can you help me?

Comment: Are you able to visit that website in a regular browser, without using python?

Comment: Yes I can access it from my Pc, this is the weird part for me.